# SESSION PHP get proid

Tags: php, session

I wanted to retrieve the proid thats in the session.
when i add to cart rdy to check out . 
The proid seems cannot to be retrieve which show empty.
but it did count the item that i entered. 
cause when i add 2 item in cart , it display 2 row.
please help me.

this is cart.php

```
if (isset($_SESSION['cart']))
{
    $total = 0;
    foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $proid =>$x)
    {
        $results = mysqli_query($con,"Select * from product where Product_ID = $proid");
        $myrow = mysqli_fetch_array($results);
        $proid = $myrow['Product_ID'];
        $productname = $myrow['Product_Name'];
        $productprice= $myrow['Product_Price'];
        $line_cost = $productprice * $x;
        $total=$total+$line_cost;
        ?>
            <li class = "cartlist">
            <?php echo  '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' . base64_encode($myrow['Product_Pic']) . '" width="196" height="120">';?>
            <p><span style = "font-weight: bold; font-size: 1.2em;">
            <?php echo $productname ?>
            </span></br />RM <?php echo $productprice;?>
            </br />Quantity : <?php echo $x ?></br><a href='cart.php?proid=<?php echo $proid;?>&action=add'>Add </a>&ensp;<a href ='cart.php?proid=<?php echo $proid;?>&action=remove'> Reduce </a></br>RM<?php echo $line_cost; ?> <br/> 
            </p> </li>
        <?php
    }
```

This is payment.php

i wanted to retrieve the proid and display the product name and total to the user.

```
print_r($_SESSION);


if (isset($_SESSION['cart']))
{

    $total = 0;
    foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $proid =>$x)
    {

        $results = mysqli_query($con,"Select * from product where Product_ID = $proid");
        $myrow = mysqli_fetch_array($results);
        $productname = $myrow['Product_Name'];
        $productprice= $myrow['Product_Price'];
        $line_cost = $productprice * $x;
        $total=$total+$line_cost;

        ?>
            <tr>
            <td><? echo $productname ?></td>
            <td><? echo $x ?></td>
            <td><? echo $line_cost ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php
    }
}
```

After adding a `print_r($_SESSION['cart']);` to the top of `payment.php` I get this output

```
Array ( [36] => 3 )
```

Comment: **Do you have a** `session_start();` **at the beginning of all of these scripts?** That is required in all scripts that require access to the session data. And is best put in ALL scripts if you use session anywhere in your site, so the session data's existance is maintained even while scripts that dont use it are running

Comment: Yeah .. All my files is included a session_start();

Comment: But I still unable to show the product detail on the other page .. I've no idea

Comment: Anyone can please help me .. Ur help is appreciated .

Comment: Add a `print_r($_SESSION);` to the top of `payment.php` and add that output to your quesiton

Comment: You mean just add print_r($_SESSION); to the top , right ? Add that output to my question ? What does that mean ?

Comment: _Add that output to my question_ That meams edit your question and add that info. Dont put it in a comment. Code in comments is almost unreadable

Comment: i've add the printr_($_SESSION); already. its show Array ( [36] => 3 ). which is correct product id inside my database and the amount i add also correct. but i have no idea when `select * from databasename where productid = $proid ` this doesnt work. but it can get the correct productid and quantity.

Comment: **Ok so I will add it to your question.**

Comment: Well quite **obviously** there is no `cart` key in your `$_SESSION` unless you did the `print_r($_SESSION);` as `print_r($_SESSION['cart']);` So how did you ACTUALLY code that statement

Comment: actually what i type in code is ` print_r(SESSION_['cart']); `

Comment: **read my lips** add this EXACT line of code to the top of `payment.php` its `print_r($_SESSION);` Then update your question

Comment: it display Array([36] =>3) Which my product id is 36 correct and the quantity is 3. the current issue is i coudlnt display the productid 36 information.

Comment: You are completely within your rights to ignore my suggestions, but remember that goes both ways.

Comment: the question edited.

Comment: in which file you have problem?

Comment: payment.php 
i can get the correct proid from the session . 
when i goes to `select * from product where Product_ID = $proid "; ` 
its then i retrieve information from database. 
but it coudlnt retrieve information. i dont know what's wrong.
but can get the correct productid tho.

Comment: $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","yourdbuser","pass","my_db");

Comment: where is your connection object?? its not declare in this file

Comment: i connected to my db. i using another php to connecting. top of the file including the php files already.

Comment: Are you doing print_r( $myrow);?